# Removing trailing values per group in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I want to remove any last grouped observations (**Value** column in example below) that are equal to zero in a data.table. I want to keep intermediate 0 values. Any help is appreciated.

```
library(data.table)

df <- structure(list(Country = c("NL", "NL", "NL", "NL", "DE", "DE", 
"DE", "GB", "GB"), Value = c(1, 2, 3, 0, 3, 0, 1, 2, 0), Value2 = c(100, 
200, 400, 500, 200, 200, 100, 800, 600)), row.names = c(NA, -9L
), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

   Country Value Value2
1:      NL     1    100
2:      NL     2    200
3:      NL     3    400
4:      NL     0    500
5:      DE     3    200
6:      DE     0    200
7:      DE     1    100
8:      GB     2    800
9:      GB     0    600
```

Desired output:

```
   Country Value Value2
1:      NL     1    100
2:      NL     2    200
3:      NL     3    400
4:      DE     3    200
5:      DE     0    200
6:      DE     1    100
7:      GB     2    800
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, here is a `data.table` solution which uses `last()` and `.I`:

```
df[!df[, last(.I[last(Value) == 0]), by = Country]$V1]
```

> ```
>    Country Value Value2
> 1:      NL     1    100
> 2:      NL     2    200
> 3:      NL     3    400
> 4:      DE     3    200
> 5:      DE     0    200
> 6:      DE     1    100
> 7:      GB     2    800
> ```

`df[, last(.I[last(Value) == 0]), by = Country]` returns the indices `.I`  into the original dataset `df` of the rows to be removed:

> ```
>    Country V1
> 1:      NL  4
> 2:      GB  9
> ```

#### Caveat

This approach as well as the other answers posted so far will only remove *one* trailing zero but not multiple trailing zeros.

#### Removing multiple trailing zeros

In case of multiple trailing zeros at the end of a country's sequence the `rle()` function can be used:

```
library(data.table)
df2[, {
  r <- rle(Value)
  if (last(r$values) == 0)
    head(.SD, -last(r$lengths))
  else
    .SD
}, Country]
```

> ```
>     Country Value Value2
>  1:      NL     1    100
>  2:      NL     2    200
>  3:      NL     3    400
>  4:      DE     3    200
>  5:      DE     0    200
>  6:      DE     1    100
>  7:      GB     2    800
>  8:      FR     1    100
>  9:      FR     0    200
> 10:      FR     3    300
> ```

#### Data

```
df2 <- fread("Country Value Value2
NL     1    100
NL     2    200
NL     3    400
NL     0    500
DE     3    200
DE     0    200
DE     1    100
GB     2    800
GB     0    600
FR     1    100
FR     0    200
FR     3    300
FR     0    400
FR     0    500")
```

Note that there are two trailing zero for `country` group `FR`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use -

```
library(data.table)
df[, .SD[!(Value == 0 & seq_len(.N) == .N)], Country]

#   Country Value Value2
#1:      NL     1    100
#2:      NL     2    200
#3:      NL     3    400
#4:      DE     3    200
#5:      DE     0    200
#6:      DE     1    100
#7:      GB     2    800
```

Without performing any grouping function you can also use `duplicated`.

```
setDT(df)[!(!duplicated(Country, fromLast = TRUE) & Value == 0)]
```

---

This can be written in `dplyr` as -

```
library(dplyr)

#1. 
df %>%
  group_by(Country) %>%
  filter(!(Value == 0 & row_number()== n())) %>%
  ungroup

#2.
df %>% filter(!(!duplicated(Country, fromLast = TRUE) & Value == 0))
```